What is the correct convergence rate for my PDE?
Let $G = (0,1)$ and $J = (0,1)$ and consider the PDE
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} &= f(t,x) \quad \text{on } G \times J, \\
u(x,0) &= u_0(x) \quad \forall x \in G, \forall t \in J, \\
u(0,t) &= u(1,t) = 0.
\end{cases}
Let in our case, $u_0(x) = x \sin(\pi x)$ and $f(t,x) = e^{-t}((\pi^2-1)x\sin(\pi x) - 2\pi\cos(\pi x))$. In this case the exact solution is known and it is given by $u(t,x) = e^{-t}\sin(\pi x)x$.
Now, I implemented a FEM $\theta$-scheme, which approximates the solution. In the following I consider the case of $\theta = 0.5$. My belief was, that this scheme has a convergence rate of 2.
Further I was given an approximate method to estimate the convergence rate for my scheme. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $h = \frac1{N+1}$ be the discretisation parameter. If the convergence rate is of the form $O(h^p)$, one can estimate, without knowing the exact solution $u$, the convergence rate $p$ by $\log\left(\frac{\| u_h - u_{h/2} \|_h}{\| u_{h/2} - u_{h/4} \|_{h/2}}\right) / \log(2)$, where $\| \cdot \|_h$ denotes the discrete $l^2$-error at the common mesh-points $j$, for $j=1,...,N$:
$$
\| u_h - u_{h/2} \|_h^2 := h \sum_{j=1}^N|u_{h,j} - u_{h/2,2j}|^2
$$
and where $u_h \in \mathbb{R}^N$ is the numerical solution computed by FEM at time $t = 1$ for the spatial mesh-width $h$.
Now, when I calculate the quantity above to approximate the convergence rate, I get $p = 1$, contradicting my belief that the convergence rate should be 2 for $\theta = 0.5$.
Is $1$ the correct convergence rate, or is there something wrong on my side? If it helps I can give you my implementation.
Thanks in advance!

what is your size of discretization for spatial variable and time variable? I doubt your dt is at the comparable size of dx.

Thanks, I forget to mention that. They are indeed of a comparable size: For $N \in \mathbb{N}$, I have $dx = \frac1{N+1}$ and $dt =\frac1N$. Does that resolve the issue?

You need to consider both time and space. The $\theta$ scheme is for the advance in time. Are you sure that de FEM scheme that you are using is second order accurate in space?

That is probably what I am confused about. So it would be possible that 'my belief' of a convergence rate of 2 only holds for advance in time. And when I consider it in space and time, a convergence rate of 1 seems plausible?
